# Azure Service Bus - Peek a scheduled message

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

Im am using Python to develop a integration that read messages from different Azure Service Bus topics and queues. But I have an issue when scheduling messages. I am not able to peek the scheduled messages. I want to peek them, and then either complete or leave them unread, until scheduled-time. I have tried to peek on both queue and topic, and I cannot find any documentation on how to peek a scheduled message on either of them. Anyone managed to do this? Should be a very common use-case. Not found anything on doing it by standard REST-calls either.

Comment: You should be able to peek messages using the `peek_messages()` in v7.0.0 https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/ - note that you cannot settle a message when you use the peek_messages function. please get started here with the v7.0.0 https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/README.md

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried peeking them by sequence number? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver.peekbysequencenumberasync?view=azure-dotnet